# Dark stains on my english ivy. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: diseases, english-ivy

I have the following problem:
Some leaves of my English Ivy became a little bit lifeless and droopy. On some leaves dark stains have appeared (I've marked them with red circles on the photo). Is my plant dying? Could you explain me what is the probable reason?
Thank you in advance for your help.
[image: The plant]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't water too much your plant. Keep it dry for sometime. Apply copper fungicide twice a week. It will be fine. And don't use fertilizer anymore.